# Make curl wait before downloading

Tags: bash, shell, unix, curl, command-line

I'm trying to download some elements from a website using cURL. However, that website loads those elements ~5 seconds after I estabilish a connection. So I want cURL to have a delay - connect to the website, sleep for ~5 seconds and only after that fetch the code. Is that possible? If not, what should I use then?
Is there any other tool I can use for my needs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think curl can do that out of the box. Your best bet is to do it from a programming language like python or javascript, where you have full control.
However, what if you use curl to try to download it (it'll fail), then reconnect a few seconds later (using `sleep` in your shell script)? Will the resource be available then?

Comment: You can also try the `--retry` and `--retry-delay` options to curl.

Comment: No, that didn't work. I just need a simple delay before the download starts - nothing more. Is there any other tool I can use besides curl? wget isn't capable of this either AFAIK.

Comment: I think you'll have to write it yourself. Python's urllib should make it pretty simple; see https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try a sort of poor man's wget:

```
(sleep 5;
 echo 'GET /foo HTTP/1.0';
 echo 'Host: example.com'
 echo '';
 sleep 10) |
    telnet example.com 80
```

This actually works to fetch `http://example.com/foo`, although it might require arbitrary amounts of tinkering to get the webserver in question to accept its handcrafted requests.